# How about yourself or what about yourself

Tags: expressions

Does the following conversation make sense?
"How are you?"
"Great. What about yourself?"

My question is whether "What about youself?" works instead of "How about youself?"

Comment: Say 'what about you?' or 'How about you?'. Remove selves.

Answer (score 1):

This thread clarifies the differences between "what about" and "how about." From my interpretation of the answers, "how about" is more appropriate.

["How about" vs. "What about"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13659/how-about-vs-what-about)

^ This is a link. ^

Comment: That "How about v What about" thread is fine, but I'm not sure it deals with the question above. In my view both "How about yourself" and "What about yourself" are a bit laboured / lengthy, and you would simply say "How about you?" or less frequently, "What about you?".  However you can use yourself as a very short phrase: "Yourself?" is quite okay.